# Xml Serialization Problem for 60mb file

Tags: c#

I want to Serialize a 60mb file into XML but it gives me System out of memory exception.
Did any one else had this kind of problem?

Can someone suggest me a workaround for this problem.

Here is the method

```
   static public string Serialize(object obj)
   {
          string returnValue;
          System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlWriter = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
          System.IO.StringWriter xmlOut = new System.IO.StringWriter();

          //this is where the problem is.....
          xmlWriter.Serialize(xmlOut, obj);
          //return the Serialized XML
          returnValue = xmlOut.ToString();
          xmlOut.Close();
          return returnValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stream that large, I think you should consider serializing to a file first.  Serializing takes a lot of memory, and doing so purely in memory is killing you.

```
using(var file = new FileStream(...))
using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file))
{
    xmlWriter.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to use the dotnet serialization libraries as they take objects. In this case, the object being in memory is the problem.

Comment: Ty: I don't understand your comment at all.  He has an object in hand, and wants to serialize it out as XML.  That is exactly what the XmlSerializer was built for.

Comment: I got hung up on the "I want to Serialize a 60mb file into XML..". I thought he meant he wanted to read a large file and parse it into something else (Xml in this case).